# How to delete all files starting with a particular name in temp folder using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to delete all log files which start with the string "MyApp" from the Windows Temp folder using the below VB Script.

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Documents and Settings\guest\MyApp") Then
          set folder = objFSO.getFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\guest\MyApp") 

if folder.files.Count <> 0 then 
    objFSO.DeleteFile "C:\Documents and Settings\guest\MyApp\*.*", True
end if 
          objFSO.DeleteFolder "C:\Documents and Settings\guest\MyApp", True
end if

<!--  The below code is not deleting the files which starts with the name "Mpp.023648011.log"   -->

if(objFSO.FileExists("C:\Documents and Settings\guest\Local Settings\Temp\MyApp.*")) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile "C:\Documents and Settings\guest\Local Settings\Temp\MyApp.*", True
end if
```

It seems the below check is failing:

if(objFSO.FileExists("C:\Documents and Settings\guest\Local Settings\Temp\MyApp.*"))

Thanks in advance.

**I found a way to suppress the error message and execute the DeleteFile. It worked for me.**

```
     On error resume next

     objFSO.DeleteFile "C:\Documents and Settings\guest\Local Settings\Temp\MyApp.*", True
```

Comment: best to publish this as an answer otherwise people keep opening this page in order to help

Comment: @peter - How I can publish this as answer.

Comment: like you answer the question of someone other, fill in the editor below and click "Post your answer", could be you have to wait for a day er so before you can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think VBScript is not supporting **FileExists** using **wildcards**. The better option is just suppress the errors from the delete and run the DeleteFile Command.

```
 On error resume next

 objFSO.DeleteFile "C:\Documents and Settings\guest\Local Settings\Temp\MyApp.*", True
```